How do 8 layers get mapped to 12 PDSCH antenna ports?
In 5G NR for PDSCH PHY processing, the scrambled bits after the modulation mapper go through a layer mapping operation followed by antenna port mapping, as shown below.

Where the maximum number of layers $(N_{\nu})$ that can be assigned is equal to $N_{\nu, \mathrm{max}} = 8$ and the maximum number of antenna ports $(N_{p})$ for PDSCH is equal to $N_{p, \mathrm{max}} = 12$ with $p = \{1000, 1001, \cdots, 1011\}$.
The antenna port mapping operation is defined in $138.211$ as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
y^{(p_0)}(i) \\
\vdots \\
y^{(p_{v-1})}(i)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
x^{(0)}(i) \\
\vdots \\
x^{(v-1)}(i)
\end{bmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
How do 8 layers get mapped to 12 antenna ports?

I guess the remaining ports could be used by other UE, the co-scheduled UE, although I didn't find direct evidence in the specification.
